# Node js. checking if any value matches 'X' in api response

Tags: node.js

I am getting an API response which I have narrowed down to just the object I need. I'm using an if/else statement to decide what to do with results.

The response from this will list objects like so:
x
y
z
x
x

I want to have two actions, one if any result matches x and one if no results match x. Not sure what to use to achieve this without having an action for each returned object...

```
success: function(result) {
      for (let i = 0; i < result.api.length; i++) {
        const issuer = (result.api[i].object);
        console.log(object)
        if (object == 'x'){
            console.log('TRUE')
        }
        else {
            console.log('FALSE')
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have tried if/else statement but this wants to perform the action on each result logged from the API.

Comment: I am confused, you don't want to look at each item? In order to check if something exists you have to look at it. Are you looking only to perform the check on a specific response? Can you provide an example of a request/response and what  you expect to happen vs what is actually happening?

Comment: No I do want to look at each item, but I only want to perform an action if any of the results are = 'x'.  So if I had 10 objects in the response and had 9 = x and 1 = y then action will be triggered. But if all 10 equal y then the code will end. If 10 equal x then we also perform that action and carry on.

Comment: I've actually solved this now so anyone else that sees this then this was the result:

success: function(result) {
  let found = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < result.api.length; i++) {
    const object = result.api[i].object;
    if (issuer === 'x') {
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (found) {
    console.log('TRUE');
  } else {
    console.log('FALSE');
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.filter` to write a case only for x.

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0):

We can use `Array.filter()` to [check for if your objects exist in the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
let tempArray = [x,y,y,z,x,x,x]
let filteredArray = tempArray.filter(obj => obj==x)
//this should return [x,x,x,x]

if(filteredArray.length > 0){
 someFunction()
}
```

We  filter the array, check to see if it retunred any values, if it did then we perform what ever function you need to